# Is there a way to get #include<bits/stdc++.h> to work?

Tags: c++, header

I am trying to get #include<bits/stdc++.h> to work. I am using it as other headers like #include , but I am not having success.

Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
```

Error:

```
Matrix.cpp:1:9: fatal error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
```

Comment: Please see ["Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Heads up: `<bits/stdc++.h>` is an internal GCC header and therefore will only work with that compiler.

Comment: Yeah, don't use it in the first place.

Comment: TL;DR - you cannot. It only works with one specific compiler that chose to have such file for some reason. But the good news is, you shouldn't use it anyway. Better only `#include` what you need.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That some reason being to make it possible to generate a 'one size fits all' precompiled header, I believe.